# Tclsh: How to get the first occurence of the string by regexp?

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a string with multiple occurring pattern. I need the extract the first pattern from the string.

i.e:

### My Pattern:

```
ABC : 1
XXX : 3
YYY : 4
ZZZ : 9

ABC : 3
XXX : 4
YYY : 6
ZZZ : 7
```

I want to extract the block based on the value provided for ABC value. 
If I give ABC value as 1, output should be:

```
ABC : 1
XXX : 3
YYY : 4
ZZZ : 9
```

I tried,

```
set ABCVal 1

regexp "ABC\[ \]+:\[ \]+$ABCVal(.*)\[^ABC\]" $buffer
```

This matches the entire buffer.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Now I have edited the question with the code snippet which i've tried.

Comment: Argh, TCL has some crazy regex syntax. Well, I'm just not used to it. In PCRE, you would use the following regex `ABC +: +1.*?(?=ABC|$)`. Replacing `1` with the appropriate value. Of course, the `s` modifier needs to be set.

Comment: @HamZa, that exact syntax works in Tcl (see [re_syntax](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) man page). However Tcl does not let you mix greedy and non-greedy quantifiers, I think the rule is "greediness of the first quantifier seen rules the whole regex", but someone more familiar with the internals will have to verify (Donal, you listening?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
package require textutil
set new [textutil::splitx $buf {(?n)^\s*\n}]
set index [lsearch -regexp $new "ABC : $ABCVal"]
puts [lindex $new $index]
```

This will give the results as
ABC : 3
XXX : 4
YYY : 6
ZZZ : 7

Answer (score 2):

I would first split the text into blank-line-separated units and then search that list for the pattern:

```
set text {ABC : 1
XXX : 3
YYY : 4
ZZZ : 9

ABC : 3
XXX : 4
YYY : 6
ZZZ : 7}
package require textutil::split
set blocks [textutil::split::splitx $text {\n{2,}}]
set abc 3
set index [lsearch -regexp $blocks "^ABC : $abc\\y"]
puts [lindex $blocks $index]
```

```
ABC : 3
XXX : 4
YYY : 6
ZZZ : 7
```

I use the regexp `\y` assertion so "^ABC : 3" does not match the text "ABC : 345"

Answer (score 0):

```
if {[regexp "(?p)^ABC : $ABCval(?=\n).*?(?=\n\n|$(?!.))" $input]} { ...
```